# GCC function call error

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have the following **C** code:

```
#ifdef _MODE_DEBUG
void program_exit(void){
#else
void program_exit(const unsigned char* fileName, unsigned int lineNumber){
    printf("The program was called to terminate early from file \"%s\" line %u", fileName, lineNumber);
#endif
//We have to call cleanup() wherever possible.
arguments_cleanup(void);

exit(1);
}
```

Which should dynamically provide only one function in the pre-compiled version of the code,depending on whether _MODE_DEBUG is defined or not. However, GCC complains that it expects all kinds of tokens before calling arguments_cleanup. Why does GCC not recognize this as a valid function, or why is this invalid?

Comment: And how to you call this function, exactly?

Comment: I call it whenever an error occurs, the function prototypes are defined in a similar way. I would call it using EXIT() which a macro changes to whatever is necessary (depending on _MODE_DEBUG)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arguments_cleanup(void);
```

isn't the correct way to call the function, it should be

```
arguments_cleanup();
```

The compiler tries to interpret

```
arguments_cleanup(void);
```

as a declaration.

Comment: Or it just treats it as a syntax error, which it is (since C99 dropped implicit `int`).

Comment: hmmm...so the void should only be used in the prototype?